# compare sets of properties to find best match

Tags: php, mysql

There seems to be problems similar to this but not quite.  I tried going down this path ( [compare data sets and return best match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1370565/compare-data-sets-and-return-best-match)  ), but found myself stumped.

I need to take on set and find the best matching set.  So say we have search_obj that contains values (1, 4, 29, 44, 378, 379).  I would like to find other objects with similar values and ideally find the one that best matches this. There will be a large amount of other objects so performance is a big concern.

I am currently working in php and mysql but am willing to change that if it means better performance.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: You might want to get real specific about what "similar" and "best match" means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It just came to my mind:

Suppose you have a table of unique pairs (a, b):

```
CREATE table t1 (a INT, b INT, PRIMARY KEY (a, b));
```

Now you fill it with:

```
INSERT INTO t1
VALUES (1,1), (1,2),               -- item to compare with
       (2,1), (2,3),               -- has one common prop with 1
       (3,1), (3,2),               -- has the same props as 1
       (4,1), (4,2), (4,3), (4,4); -- has 2 same props with 1
```

The following query will order the other items according to similarity:

```
SELECT t1.a,
    COUNT(t2.a) as same_props_count,
    ABS(COUNT(t2.a) - COUNT(*)) as diff_count
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t1 as t2 ON t1.b = t2.b and t2.a = 1
WHERE t1.a <> 1
GROUP BY t1.a
ORDER BY same_props_count DESC, diff_count;


a, same_props_count, diff_count
3, 2,                0
4, 2,                2
2, 1,                1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can compute the intersection of two arrays using `array_intersect`, which returns values of the first array that are present in the second. If you're comparing against multiple lists then you can use the length of the return array (i.e. the greater the length the closer the intersection, therefore, the closer the match).