# Finding similar records based on a connector table with many-to-many relations

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables `Products,ProductHas,Props`. Needless to say each product has more than one prop which is kept in the `ProductHas` table. I'm trying to find the `Product B` which is closest to `Product A` interms of similarities of their props.

Current structure of the tables look like this.

```
+----------+----------+-----------+
|Products  |ProductHas|Props      |
+----------+----------+-----------+
|product_id|product_id|prop_id    |
+----------+----------+-----------+
|   name   | prop_id  |description|
+----------+----------+-----------+
```

Comment: You will need to define "similarities" a bit more rigorously...

Comment: @David M has most amount of props in common

Comment: Regardless of number not in common?

Comment: @DavidM yes trying to keep it simple... although that might be useful as well...

Comment: take a look at the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8498887/compare-sets-of-properties-to-find-best-match/8501078#8501078

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT  B.product_id
FROM    Products B
        INNER JOIN
                ProductHas HB
                INNER JOIN
                        ProductHas HA
                        INNER JOIN
                                Products A
                                ON HA.product_id = A.product_id
                        ON HA.prop_id = HB.prop_id
                        AND HA.product_id != HB.product_id
                ON B.product_id = HB.product_id
WHERE   A.product_id = xxx
GROUP BY B.product_id
ORDER BY COUNT(A.product_id) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: It doesn't run in mysql... judging from the top its for ms sql perhaps?

Comment: Remove the TOP 1 and replace with LIMIT 1 at the end, if memory serves me rightly - editing answer...

Comment: thanks I've already done that, but it will get errors with the on parts which is why I ended up changing the on parts to something that looks like this https://gist.github.com/1565625 after my alterations it only returns the products with the most props, instead of most props in common...

Answer (score 0):

Another option

```
SELECT  A.Name, B.Name, COUNT(*)
FROM    (
          SELECT  p.name, pp.description
          FROM    Products p
                  INNER JOIN ProductHas ph ON ph.product_id = p.product_id
                  INNER JOIN Props pp ON pp.prop_id = ph.prop_id
        ) AS A INNER JOIN (
          SELECT  p.name, pp.description
          FROM    Products p
                  INNER JOIN ProductHas ph ON ph.product_id = p.product_id
                  INNER JOIN Props pp ON pp.prop_id = ph.prop_id
        ) AS B ON B.description = A.Description
WHERE   A.Name = 'A'        
GROUP BY
        A.name, B.Name
ORDER BY
        COUNT(*) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select h1.product_id, count(h0.prop_id) count_matches, count(*) total_props
from ProductHas h1
left join ProductHas h0 
on h0.product_id = ? and h0.prop_id = h1.prop_id and h0.product_id <> h1.product_id
group by h1.product_id
order by 2 desc
limit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try a [`fulltext`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-natural-language.html) index on the props table, i

```
CREATE TABLE Props(
   prop_id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   description TEXT,
   FULLTEXT (description)
 ) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

(I don't know anything about the size of the description but if you know its limit then you should put it like `description VARCHAR(200)`)

```
SELECT * 
 FROM Props prod_a_props, 
   Props prod_b_props, 
   ProductHas prod_a_rel
 WHERE prod_a_rel.product_id = :your_product_A_id
   AND prod_a_props.prop_id = prod_a_rel.prop_id
   AND MATCH (prod_b_props.description) AGAINST (prod_a_props.description);
```